# C# Regular expression combination

Tags: c#, regex

I just wondered if I can combine these two expressions into one.

```
 Regex comb1 = new Regex("[A-Z0-9]{4,6}-[A-Z0-9]{4,6}-[A-Z0-9]{4,6}");
 Regex comb2 = new Regex("[A-Z0-9]{4,6}-[A-Z0-9]{4,6}-[A-Z0-9]{4,6}-[A-Z0-9]{4,6}");
```

Answer (score 4):

In general you would use alternations (`|`) to match one of a several patterns. For example:

```
aaa|bbb
```

Will first attempt to match the pattern `aaa` and then attempt to pattern `bbb`.

However, because your patterns are so similar, you could just use something like this:

```
[A-Z0-9]{4,6}(-[A-Z0-9]{4,6}){2,3}
```

This will match any sequence of four to six alphanumeric characters, followed by a hyphen and four to six alphanumeric characters, which must be repeated two or three times.

Comment: +1 Nice direct answer (to use `|`) as well as alternative Regex that does the trick.

Comment: It's the same concept like the [A-Z0-9]{4,6}.

Comment: @user3381113 That's correct. [Quantifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx) can be applied in precisely the same way to characters, character classes, or groups.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an optional part in a pattern, you can use `(OptionalPattern)?`, so your code could become:

```
[A-Z0-9]{4,6}-[A-Z0-9]{4,6}-[A-Z0-9]{4,6}(-[A-Z0-9]{4,6})?
```

But pswg's `{2,3}` is a better choice here, since it also eliminates the unnecessary repetition in your pattern. I'm just mentioning since it can be useful in similar situations.